# sound effects on/off in spritekit game

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ios7, sprite-kit

In the gameScene.m how we can make on/off music with skspritenode  while playing the game ,with the below code i can play sounds perfectly  but i want on/off whenever user wants to on or off the sounds in game to play their own ipad.

```
//.h file
#import <SpriteKit/SpriteKit.h>
@interface MyScene : SKScene


//.m file
#import "MyScene.h"
#import <AVFoundation/AVAudioPlayer.h>
@interface MyScene() <SKPhysicsContactDelegate>
@end

@import AVFoundation;

@implementation MyScene 
{AVAudioPlayer *_AudioPlayer;}



-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
if (_gameLayer.speed > 0) {
    //for flying plane
    _playerPlane.physicsBody.velocity = CGVectorMake(0, 0);
    [_playerPlane.physicsBody applyImpulse:CGVectorMake(0, 14)];
    [self jumpsound]; 
}
-(void)didBeginContact:(SKPhysicsContact *)contact{
       _gameLayer.speed = 0;
        [self removeAllActions];
       skspritenodeGameOver.hidden = NO;
       [self hitSound];}

- (void)jumpsound
{
NSURL *file = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"jump" ofType:@"wav"]];
_AudioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:file error:nil];

[_AudioPlayer setVolume:0.5];
[_AudioPlayer play];  
}

- (void)hitsound
{
  NSURL *file = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"jump" ofType:@"wav"]];
_AudioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:file error:nil];

[_AudioPlayer setVolume:0.5];
[_AudioPlayer play];  
}
@end
```

Comment: You can pause the music with [_backgroundAudioPlayer pause] or stop it with [_backgroundAudioPlayer stop].

Comment: i know this play, pause and stop but i want to on/off for all my 3 sounds to stop at same time ?

Comment: Are you trying to play background music in your game or sound effects?

Comment: sound effects only like jump, hit , points and crash but if user wants to mute/off these sounds so i need like on/off options

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add sound effects to your game, I suggest using playSoundFileNamed SKAction instead of AVAudioPlayer. Here's an example of how to do that:

```
@property BOOL playSounds;

// Define action to play a sound effect
_playJumpSound = [SKAction playSoundFileNamed@"jump.wav" waitForCompletion:NO];

// Play sound effect only if playSounds is set
if (_playSounds) {
  [self runAction:_playJumpSound];
}
```

**EDIT:** Add sounds to methods. Sound will only play if _playSounds == YES.

```
- (void) playJumpSound
{
    if (_playSounds) {
        [self runAction:_playJumpSound];
    }
}

- (void) playHitSound
{
    if (_playSounds) {
        [self runAction:_playHitSound];
    }
}
```

Comment: its working fine but i am concerned about on/off button while playing i want to ON to play all sounds and OFF to stop all sounds with button

Comment: Are you asking how to create a button or how the button will turn on/off the sound?

Comment: how the button will turn on/off the sounds

Comment: If the button is on, set _playSound = YES, else set _playSound = NO.

Comment: thanks for helping me i figured it out with ur help